# onPostExecute won't be called though doInBackground was processed and ended normally

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-asynctask

I made the following sample program to check if onPostExecute will work after doInBackground.
For this case, my understanding is that doPostExecute works after the doInBackground using the result of doInBackground which is String ab.
But after the doInBackground, it goes to AsyncTask(@Nullable Looper callbackLooper) which is in AsyncTask.java.
I am not sure why it does not go to onPostExecute even though doInBackground processed normally with appropriate form to be forwarded to onPostExecute.
Are there any missing things that need to be taken care of?

```
public void search(String word){
        AsyncSearch as = new AsyncSearch();
        as.execute(word);     
    }

    private class AsyncSearch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... word) {
            try {
                String string = aaa(word[0]);
                return string;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return  null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String string){
            System.out.println(string);
            //and forward the string to the other method
        }

       public String aaa(String word) throws IOException {
            String ab = word + "test";
            return ab;
        }
    }
```

At this point, after the doInBackground(), the following in AsyncTask was called somehow.

```
mWorker = new WorkerRunnable<Params, Result>() {
            public Result call() throws Exception {
                mTaskInvoked.set(true);
                Result result = null;
                try {
                    Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                    //noinspection unchecked
                    result = doInBackground(mParams);
                    Binder.flushPendingCommands();
                } catch (Throwable tr) {
                    mCancelled.set(true);
                    throw tr;
                } finally {
                    postResult(result);
                }
                return result;
            }
        };
```

And the following error came up on the console.
[image]

I am not sure if that relates to the above phenomenon.

Would you mind giving me some help?
Thank you.

Comment: oPostExecute is not called on background thread , it is called on the main thread , so after completing the doInBackground() the thread is cleared

Comment: So , how can I use the onPostExecute?

Comment: it will be called after the doInBackGround() on the main thread you don't call it , all you do is new yourAsycTask().execute(), and all methods runs as they should

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Based on your comment, the above sample should work. But it does not. I'm not sure why it won't be called after the doInBackGround().

Comment: if you're passing only one argument in the execute then you should access it as word[0] because it is a vararg

Comment: so what exactly was your output

Comment: I changed to "word[0]", but still the same. There is no output. 
After doInBackGround(), the above in AsyncTask.java was called.

Comment: please share the github link , i shall run it myself

Comment: Did you annotate the methods `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` with `@Override`? If not, please do so and try again.

Comment: I will send you the link to Github.
I added @Override , but the result was the same.